# Kotlin Coroutine wait for Retrofit Response

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to use the Android `MVVM` pattern with a repository class and `Retrofit` for network calls. I have the common problem that I can't get the coroutine to wait for the network response to return.

This method is in my `ViewModel` class:

```
private fun loadConfigModel() {
    val model = runBlocking {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            configModelRepository.getConfigFile()
        }
    }
    configModel.value = model
}
```

In `ConfigModelRepository`, I have this:

```
suspend fun getConfigFile(): ConfigModel {
    val configString = prefs.getString(
        ConfigViewModel.CONFIG_SHARED_PREF_KEY, "") ?: ""

    return if (configString.isEmpty() || isCacheExpired()) {
        runBlocking { fetchConfig() }
    } else {
        postFromLocalCache(configString)
    }
}

private suspend fun fetchConfig(): ConfigModel {
    return suspendCoroutine { cont ->
         dataService
            .config()  // <-- LAST LINE CALLED
            .enqueue(object : Callback<ConfigModel> {
                 override fun onResponse(call: Call<ConfigModel>, response: Response<ConfigModel>) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        response.body()?.let {
                            saveConfigResponseInSharedPreferences(it)
                            cont.resume(it)
                        }
                    } else {
                        cont.resume(ConfigModel(listOf(), listOf()))
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ConfigModel>, t: Throwable) {
                    Timber.e(t, "config fetch failed")
                    cont.resume(ConfigModel(listOf(), listOf()))
                }
            })
    }
}
```

My code runs as far as `dataService.config()`. It never enters `onResponse` or `onFailure`. The network call goes and and returns properly (I can see this using Charles), but the coroutine doesn't seem to be listening for the callback.

So, my question is the usual one. How can I get the coroutines to block such that they wait for this callback from `Retrofit`? Thanks.

Comment: You could mark your Retrofit API call with `suspend` and have it return `ConfigModel`, instead of using the legacy callback mechanism and `suspendCoroutine`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem must be that `response.body()` returns `null` since that is the only case that is missing a call to `cont.resume()`. Make sure to call `cont.resume()` also in that case and your code should at least not get stuck.

But like CommonsWare points out, even better would be to upgrade to Retrofit 2.6.0 or later and use native `suspend` support instead of rolling your own `suspendCoroutine` logic.

You should also stop using `runBlocking` completely. In the first case, `launch(Dispatchers.Main)` a coroutine instead and move `configModel.value = model` inside of it. In the second case you can just remove `runBlocking` and call `fetchConfig()` directly.

Comment: I had tried this earlier, but it was failing. Your answer tipped me off to the fact that I was only on Retrofit 2.4. Thanks for the suggestions!